# Libreoffice Can't Export PDF?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, libreoffice, pdf

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04LTS (Latest Updates), and my version of Libreoffice seems to be broken somehow.

When I go to export a PDF of something, including a brand new document, I get "general input/output error", or a random crash.

I have no idea what happened and I haven't touched the system in a while except to update things.

I tried purging libreoffice (And removeing the `~/.config/libreoffice` folder) and reinstalling, but this didn't solve the issue. I don't know if I missed some config files or something when I purged libreoffice*, but it didn't work.

Safe mode also doesn't seem to work and gives the same error.

Not sure where to go from here. What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend reinstallation of LibreOffice using these steps:

1. Add the LibreOffice PPA:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
2. Update your system:

   sudo apt update
3. Upgrade or Install LibreOffice 6:

   sudo apt install libreoffice

Once done, you should be good to go.

Comment: Is this really a good idea? The PPA message says that it is for testing. This seems to me that it will likely break in the future due to little testing.

Comment: As you see fit but I installed LO this way well over a year ago and it ain't broke yet. Get all the up-to-date updates too.